# How should we clean up the [kvm] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

#### ***This is a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) about a tag, not an invitation to mass-edit questions containing said tag (at least for now)*****

We have a [kvm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm) tag. It is meant to be about [Kernel-based Virtual Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel-based_Virtual_Machine) (based on [the Tag Wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/kvm/info) for it). We also have a [kvm-switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm-switch) tag for questions pertaining to [KVM switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch).

I recently noticed a few Suggested Edits that re-tagged questions that were (wrongly) tagged with the [kvm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm) tag to use the [kvm-switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm-switch) tag (for questions about KVM switches). These edits aren't wrong at all.

However, I noticed there's about 1,100 questions tagged with the [kvm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm) tag, [104 of which also contain the word "switch"](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bkvm%5D+%22switch%22). In addition, [28 questions tagged with `kvm` include the phrase "kvm switch"](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bkvm%5D+%22kvm+switch%22). There's also [three questions tagged with both the `kvm` tag and the `kvm-switch` tag](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm-switch+kvm).

I haven't gone through all 104 questions that contain the [kvm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm) and the word "switch", but a quick glance indicates many (most?) are about KVM switches (although at least a couple are actually about Kernel-based Virtual Machines).

So, what should we with the [kvm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm) tag? Some initial ideas include:

- Keep the [kvm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm) tag, clean up the wrongly-tagged questions, and [request a tag warning for that tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299884/how-do-we-get-a-custom-warning-when-asking-a-question-on-a-stack-exchange-site) Pros: Less work,
- Create a [kernel-virtual-machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kernel-virtual-machine) tag, and retag all questions tagged with [kvm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm) to either [kernel-virtual-machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kernel-virtual-machine) or [kvm-switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm-switch). Pros: tag name is unambigous Cons: Retagging tons of questions is a lot of work, and would likely heavily polute the front page*

---

*It might be possible to rename the [kvm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm) tag to [kernel-virtual-machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kernel-virtual-machine) and then just re-tag those questions, and that might be easier, but I'm not sure

**This should be obvious, but several of my other tag-related Meta questions (on MSO) have resulted in other users deciding to take action on a tag before consensus was reached, so I'm trying to avoid that issue here

Comment: I'd suggest renaming `kvm` to `kvm-virtualization` so that the context is clear, because in practice I've never heard anyone say "kernel virtual machine". It will also contrast nicely with `kvm-switch`

Comment: Mods can rename tags (and IIRC it's possible to make the old tag name a synonym as well when renaming), so renaming to `kernel-virtual-machine` while keeping `kvm` as a synonym might also be a good idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some further discussion with @cocomac on [Raiders of the Lost Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat) the following changes have now been completed:

[image]

A few tasks remain:

1. Some re-tagging of posts tagged [kvm-virtualization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm-virtualization) to [kvm-switch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm-switch) as appropriate which cocomac has agreed to undertake.
2. Usage guidelines and a tag wiki will need to be added to the the new [kvm-virtualization](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/kvm-virtualization) which is currently barren of any useful details.

And thanks again to cocomac for finding the issue, bringing it forward to the Community and acting on it!

**References:**

- [Moderator Cheat Sheet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119111/moderator-cheat-sheet#119377): The canonical guide to manipulating tags